# Rebase is not just replaying the changes?

Tags: git, git-rebase

From what I understand, rebase replays the commits of the current branch on the target branch. If I understand it correctly, than if I rebase my branch on top of another branch any possible conflicts can occur only on files I have changed, but it doesn't, and I get conflicts also on files I did not change in my commits (although they are different between the two branches).

Just to be clearer, assume branch Main and A.

- I create a new branch from A called "newA".
- Make a few changes on files A.h and A.cpp.

time goes by and Main branch changes quite a lot, but A.h and A.cpp still exists.

- Now I want to rebase newA back on top of Main.

I expect that if there are any conflicts they will occur **only** on A.h and A.cpp, but from what I experience I also get conflicts on other files. What am I missing???

Thanks!!!

Comment: Does newA have only files A.h and A.cpp? If not, I'd say that it's working as expected.

Comment: newA changes only these 2 files, so why a rebase would conflict other files?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase IS just replaying the changes. If you run into conflicts with also other files, then the commit history of Main before the branching point must have changed.